# How to quote spaces in the command of a "for /F" loop on Windows

Tags: windows, for-loop, escaping, quotes, spaces

I have the following `for` command

```
for /F %s in ('"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p mass ter') do echo %s
```

And I don't get it to work properly. It is not the actual use-case, but a much simplified example.

Executing

```
"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p "mas ter"
```

works fine,

```
"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p mass ter
```

says that the project direcotry "mass" does not exist (extra "s" for distinguisihing purpose only),

```
mas ter\gradlew.bat -q -p mass ter
```

says command "mas" was not found.

So far so expected, but now I want to get it working in the for loop.

```
for /F %s in ('mas ter\gradlew.bat -q -p mass ter') do echo %s
```

of course says again that command "mas" was not found,

```
for /F %s in ('"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p mass ter') do echo %s
```

of course says again that project direcotry "mass" does not exist but now it comes,

```
for /F %s in ('"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p "mass ter"') do echo %s
```

again says that command "mas" was not found. o_O

And now I'm at wtf.
Why is this happening and how do I make it work?
It also does not work to escape the spaces with `^` characters.
Besides that, this wouldn't help, because the two paths are stored in parameters and are used like

```
for /F %s in ('"%script_path%\gradlew.bat" -q -p "%script_path%"') do echo %s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was really a frustrating one because the parsing of command is weird

```
('"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p mass ter')
```

But you can't have double quotes in both first and any other param

```
('"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p "mass ter"')
```

Something of below would work fine

```
('master\gradlew.bat -q -p mass ter')
```

So I came with few things for this to work

**par ams.bat**

A file with space in name and echo each parameter. I also create copy of same as `params.bat`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo "You sent '%*'"
set argC=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    Set /A argC+=1
    echo !argC! is %%x
)
echo %argC%

F:\params.sh>"par ams.bat" 1 2 "ab c"
"You sent '1 2 "ab c"'"
1 is 1
2 is 2
3 is "ab c"
3
```

This shows what I need to do.

Now a file to test the setup

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in (params.bat " -q" "  -p " "abc"`) do echo %%s
```

this worked great

```
"You sent '" -q" "  -p " "abc"'"
0 is " -q"
0 is "  -p "
0 is "abc"
3
```

Next was to try `par ams.bat`. I tried different variations

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('par ams.bat " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('"par ams.bat" " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('par ams.bat' " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%s in (`'par ams.bat' " -q" "  -p " "abc"`) do echo %%s
for /F "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%s in (`"par ams.bat" " -q" "  -p " "abc"`) do echo %%s
```

And none of the above worked. So the conclusion was that first param without space and then any param with space or quotes, no issues. So I came up with a additional batch file

**escape.bat**

```
@echo off
SET COMMAND=%~1
SHIFT
%COMMAND %%*
```

The file does nothing but takes first parameter as what to execute and then command line arguments for the same. And now I updated the test to use

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('escape.bat "par ams.bat" " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
```

And then it worked

```
F:\params.sh>test
"You sent '" -q" "  -p " "abc"'"
0 is " -q"
0 is "  -p "
0 is "abc"
3
```

**Edit-1: Using call instead of escape.bat**

Thanks for the feedback on this @Vampire. So a better way is to use `call` instead of a `escape.bat`. Also you can get the script directory using `set script_dir=%~dp0` and then use the same in your batch file. So we will change

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('escape.bat "par ams.bat" " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
```

to

```
set script_name=%~dp0
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%s in ('call "%script_name%\par ams.bat" " -q" "  -p " "abc"') do echo %%s
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Vampire, then probably why not use `set script_dir=%~sdp0` to get 8.3 name and then no need for call also?

Comment: A now deleted question also suggested 8.3 names, unfortunately they can be deactivated and even if they get activated only newly created paths get one. For me e. g. C has them activated, D deactivated and I didn't do it intentionally. So using 8.3 names is not very failsafe. Otherwise it would have been a valid solution, because then you would never need quotes around the command.

Comment: Old question, but you fix the parameter indexing in params.bat with "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" and using ! instead of %.  The %-substitution happens before the loop runs.  !-substitution happens when the statement runs, each time.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I don't have any Windows machine anymore. If you want I would suggest add a additional section to the answer with your finding

Comment: I'll go ahead and edit that in, and you can roll back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

**Executive summary:**

Enclose the command string in another set of double-quotes regardless of whether or not quotes are used in the command string (just leave those alone):

```
for /F %s in ('""%script_path%\gradlew.bat" -q -p "%script_path%""') do echo %s
```

**tl;dr details:**

It appears that the `for /f ... ('command')` variant just passes the command string to `cmd /c` (or some equivalent internal code) to actually run the command.

In general, cmd.exe has complicated, haphazard, and buggy quote handling rules. The particular rules for `cmd /c` includes these copied from `cmd /?` help text:

```
the following logic is used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

(who came up with that stuff?)

What this boils down to for me is that it's best just to enclose the command string in a set of double-quotes regardless of whether or not quotes are used in the command string (just leave those alone).

Here's a batch file that is in a path containing a space - `mas ter\gradlew.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo "Running '%~dpnx0'"

:echo_args
    if "" == "%1" goto :eof
    echo arg: %1
    shift
```

Here's a run of that batch file without the `for` loop:

```
C:\temp>"mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p "mass ter"
"Running 'C:\temp\mas ter\gradlew.bat'"
arg: -q
arg: -p
arg: "mass ter"
```

And here is it used in a `for` loop with an enclosing set of double-quotes::

```
C:\temp>for /F "tokens=*" %s in ('""mas ter\gradlew.bat" -q -p "mass ter""') do @echo from the for loop: "%s"
from the for loop: ""Running 'C:\temp\mas ter\gradlew.bat'""
from the for loop: "arg: -q"
from the for loop: "arg: -p"
from the for loop: "arg: "mass ter""
```